# mypy, lambda, and QThread.quit() | QThread.deleteLater()

Tags: python, lambda, pyside, pyside6

I have several worker/thread setups in my application which I am currently refactoring to support mypy.

The setup is always similar to the following:

```py
self._test_thread = QThread()
self._test_worker = TestWorker()
self._test_worker.moveToThread(self._test_thread)

# Bind all the signals to the slots
self._test_thread.started.connect(self._test_worker.run)
self._test_worker.finished.connect(lambda: {
    self._test_thread.quit(),
    self._test_thread.wait(),
    self._test_worker.deleteLater(),
    self._some_custom_ui_change_method(),
    self.ui.btn_test.setEnabled(True),
})
```

The problem is that mypy reports an error for `.quit()` and `.deleteLater()` of the QTread class.

The following error is displayed `Mypy: "quit" of "QThread" does not return a value [func-returns-value]`.

Both methods are annotated with `-> None'. Is there a rule that lamdas can only consist of returning statements? If so, is creating an extra function for the five statements a good solution?

Comment: Why are you using a set?! That seems a terrible idea: sets don't keep insertion order, so there's absolutely no absolute guarantee about the order of those calls, and even if syntactically it would be valid, just create an appropriate function, which, ***YES***, would be far better for readability and debugging than that awful bunch of calls. There's no minimum length requirement for functions: even if it just has one line, the purpose and readability of that function is what matters. So, create functions, don't use lambdas like that, there's absolutely ***NO*** benefit in doing it.

Comment: After some thinking, I realized that using a set *could* be safe, since lambdas evaluate their content when executed, and since the "insertion" is what calls the function, it shouldn't really matter. But here's the fact: while sets may be extremely fast, they also need to check if every new item is already in it, something tuples never need to do, so, any speed benefit a set creation could get would be lost anyway. Still, the fact remains: using a lambda like this makes no sense, it's just awful to read and terrible to debug. If you don't want or cannot create a method, use a local function.